# Total Bill of Materials Quantity Calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently working on an excel spreadsheet of engineering bill of materials. Please reference the example below:

> 1 main assembly   Qty - 1   Total Qty - 1;
> 1.1 sub assembly  Qty - 2   Total Qty - Qty of 1.1 * Total Qty of 1 = 2;
> 1.1.1 parts involved in the sub assembly  Qty - 4   Total Qty - 8;
> 1.1.2 part  Qty - 2  Total Qty - Qty of 1.1.2 * Total Qty of 1.1 = 4;
> 1.1.3 part  Qty - 4  Total Qty - Qty of 1.1.3 * Total Qty of 1.1 = 8;

Is there a function or formula to calculate the total quantity of each part for that sub assembly and assembly specific. As there are more than 1000 rows in the spread sheet if there is a way other than manually doing it would save up lot of time and prevent errors. I have attached the image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

[image: Value not available error]

Comment: @Euler's - Thanks for your reply. it does not work for the ones with item no with 7 chars, 1.3.1.1 or 1.4.2.2 but otherwise its good. let me know if there is a way to go about this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=LET(x, LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,".","")),
y, LEFT($A2, FIND("!", SUBSTITUTE($A2, ".", "!", x), 1)-1),
IF(x=0, $B2,
$B2*INDEX($A$2:$C$14, MATCH(y, TEXT($A$2:$A$14, "General"),0),3)))
```

The steps:

1. We use the `LET` function to name variables.
2. We count the number of instances a decimal appears (indicating the parent-child relationship) with `LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,".",""))` and call this count "x".
3. We find the parent of the last child using `LEFT($A2, FIND("!", SUBSTITUTE($A2, ".", "!", x), 1)-1)`. Note that the right part of the equation finds the last instance of a decimal and that the character '!' is chosen at random; it could be anything that wouldn't normally appear in the string.
4. We finally use an `IF` statement. If it is the main parent, the total quantity is just the quantity, otherwise it is the quantity multiplied by the parent's total quantity. Note that we wrap the range we are looking up in the `INDEX\MATCH` as a text string and use "3" as a fixed reference only because we know the position of the "Total QTY" column and don't anticipate it moving.

EDITED IMAGE TO SHOW FUNCTION IN ACTION ON NEW DATA:
[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you very much that did solve it partially. But the parent is not gonna be always three characters, it will be 1.11, 1.21 too. Also, the main parent which will be a integer. How to go about that. Thanks. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a way to go about for item numbers with 7 characters such as 1.2.1.1 or 1.3.3.2 , they seemed to be multiplying the quantity to the parent rather than the sub parent. Thanks in advance @EulersD. Also I am not sure how to add in the image here.

Comment: @Cybertruck , I understand now. See my edits, it gets a little bit trickier, but the formula should do the trick

Comment: @EulersD - It worked. Saved up a lot of time. I dont think I would have ever got to the solution. Really appreciate for taking your time to solve. Cheers

Comment: @Eulers Disgraced - Hey I am having trouble again, when I tried to incorporate the same formula/function in the main excel workbook. The problem I am currently facing is, for example: 1.5.2.1 & 1.5.2.2 does not multiply the quantity to the parent of them which is 1.5.2 rather they multiply to the main parent 1 for some reason. Not sure whats going on. It works well till level 3 which 1.1.2 or with 3 decimal places.

Comment: @Cybertruck Weird, I'm not sure why that is. For example, in the image you can see that 1.12.12.1 multiplies the quantity (3) by the parent's (1.12.12) total quantity (10) to get 30. My only guess is that your range is not correct. Are you sure that you are ```INDEX``` ing the full and relevant range (i.e. ```$A$2:$C$xxx``` and ```$A$2:$A$xxx```) of your main workbook?

Comment: Yea it is so weird. Oh I just figured out, it does that thing only for the that exact item no. The other ones are alright.

Comment: Also, it does not work with level 5 which are like 2.2.3.1.1 Could you modify the formula such that it works

Comment: @Eulers Disgraced - I think we might be missing out a conidition,

Comment: @Cybertruck see my edited picture which adds in more levels to show it working for all cases. It should work regardless of how many levels you add. What is the exact formula you are using? Are you sure that you are referencing everything correctly/using dollar signs where needed/signifying the correct row and column numbers?

Comment: =LET(x, LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,".","")),
y, LEFT($A2, FIND("!", SUBSTITUTE($A2, ".", "!", x), 1)-1),
IF(x=0, $C2,
$C2*INDEX($A$2:$D$364, MATCH(y, TEXT($A$2:$A$364, "General"),0),3))) This is the formula I am using. yea I am sure. Is there way that I can send you some pictures so you know whats going on

Comment: If Column C is the total quantity, what are columns B and D doing? If your total quantity is in Column D, you need to change all the C's to D's, and the final column reference from 3 to 4

Comment: Disgraced Child - Column B is assigned to something else. Column C is the Quantity of each them and Column D is where I calculate the total Quantity. So should I still change?

Comment: The example picture you have got there, there is no level 5. Try it out on yours let me know if it works.

Comment: @Eulers Disgraced - Sorry, it works my bad. When I altered the columns to what you had it works pretty good. So I am just gonna stick with that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235290/discussion-between-cybertruck-and-eulers-disgraced-stepchild).

Comment: I have edited my response to show the function working with your exact data in addition to a couple other cases. It is likely you did not have the correct references

Comment: Hi @Euler's Disgraced Stepchild, I got a minor problem not sure how to fix it. I am getting value not available error in the total qty column only for the item no. with 1.10, 2.10, 2.20, 2.20.1, 2.20.2 and so on which in general format it becomes as 1.1 in the column as I increase the decimal place still get N/A. I know it has something to do with the formatting. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ah I see how that might be a problem. I don't have an answer for you now, but let me think about it. Off the top of my head, maybe you can change both references to text and it won't eliminate the trailing zero. Or if not, maybe add a character at the end of every reference and lookup (like 1.10a) in the formula. Play around with either of those and I will think about ways on my end and reply to you if I think of something

Comment: Didnt seem to work. Let me know if you find a way to get it working. Thanks

Comment: First, store 1.10 as 1.10 by prefacing with an apostrophe ("'1.10"). Next, add more criteria to the last ```IF``` that checks whether the value to the right of the last period is 10. If it is, change your ```MATCH``` to ```MATCH(y, $A$2:$A$9999,0)``` (get rid of the text formatting).

Comment: Hi Euler, back at this again. Could you please send me an updated function as you suggested above for 1.10 case.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution for the issue with zeroes. I tried replacing zeroes with symbol "s" (column A). Mine table is a little bigger, so `INDEX` and `MATCH` range correct for your table.

I hope it works

```
=LET(x; LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2;"0";"s"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2;"0";"s");".";""));
y; TEXT(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE($A2;"0";"s"); FIND("!"; SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2;"0";"s"); "."; "!"; x); 1)-1);"general");
 IF(x=0; $D2; $D2*INDEX($A$2:$I$999;
 MATCH(y; TEXT(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$999;"0";"s"); "General");0);9)))
```